# How do I achieve this design in Illustrator? Im assuming its a stroke? but it fills in the shape perfectly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, shapes

[image: EMBROIDERY EFFECT]

How do I achieve this design in Illustrator? Im assuming its a stroke? but it takes fills in the shape perfectly....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a filter that is applied to the shape.
Select the object and go up to the Effect menu > Illustrator Effects: Stylize > Scribble.
The default settings look fairly sloppy, but if you set the curviness and variation sliders to their minimums, you'll get the tidy effect you see in your example.[image]

Comment: WOW!!! thank you sooo much! I really appreciate your helpful answers :)

Comment: This method has quite some nifty uses on a laser engraver

Answer (score 7):

- Draw a shape
- Fill the shape with a color
- Select the shape
- Choose `Effect > Stylize > Scribble` and play

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I really appreciate the helpful and quick answers!!! :)

Comment: I'm new to this site, but how can I rate the answers I get for my questions so that I can properly credit, and give gratitude and let the person who answered know that it was helpful? I dont seem to see any checkmarks or buttons option that i can click. Is writing a good comment simply enough? In any case Thank you :) it was very helpful.

Comment: Hi @claudia -- At the top left of an answer you should see up/down arrows and a check mark. You can up vote good answers, down vote bad answers and the check mark marks an answer as correct or selected.

Comment: Thank you :)  DONE!